# How to eliminate APCu misses?

Tags: php, apache, caching, fpm, apcu

we use APCu to cache some arrays instead of fetching them from our database everytime. I know, that some misses are normal but as you can see in the image below, half of the requests are misses. We can't find any problems in the source code. We are storing Arrays in the cache. Is this a problem?

Can you please give us some hints to fix this?

[image: APCu Cache Information]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/607637/apcu-no-hit-and-or-miss-what-am-i-missing

here a Info!?!